# Realm accessed from incorrect thread - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm, grand-central-dispatch

At the top of my `UITableViewController` is the following:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "background")
```

When a task is deleted, the following executes:

```
self.queue.async {
    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.delete(task)
        do {
            try realm.commitWrite()
        } catch let error {
            self.presentError()
        }
    } 
 }
```

And then I receive the error

> terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the write is happening on a different thread than the object was originally accessed from. You should be able to fix it by passing `task`'s id and using that to fetch it from the database right before you do the write (inside the async block).

So at the top:

```
var taskId = 0  // Set this accordingly
```

and then something like

```
self.queue.async {
    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let tempTask = // get task from Realm based on taskId
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.delete(tempTask)
        do {
            try realm.commitWrite()
        } catch let error {
            self.presentError()
        }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Ah so I cannot read from main thread (UI thread) if I want to write? Should I be reconsidering using threading at all then?

Comment: Yeah, there is something about Realm crashing when objects get passed between threads. This has happened to me a lot :)

Comment: Do you think there would be any advantages in threading the writes if I also have to do an extra read?

Comment: I think that depends on personal preference and/or your app. If it's slowing down the UI to do all the deletes on the main thread, then I could see using the async block...but if it doesn't really impact the app's responsiveness then it probably would be simpler (and few database operations) to keep all on one thread.

Comment: Thanks for this! This is how we recommend offloading work to the background thread. You can set `taskId` as the primary key of the Realm object, and then retrieve a reference to it on a background thread by using `Realm.object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)`.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, we recommend offloading long-lasting Realm write transactions to the background thread as much as possible. It's possible to continue reading from Realm on other threads mid-write, but you need to be wary that if a write is in progress in the background and you try and start one on the main thread, that will block your UI until the background operation has completed.

Answer (score 4):

We need to understand the fact  **Realm Objects cannot be accessed from different threads.** What does this means and how to workout this issue.

First, realm objects cannot be access from different thread means, one instance of Realm defined in one thread cannot be access from different thread.  What we should do actually is we need to have different instance of realm instance for each thread.

For eg. let's look at following e.g. where we insert 50 records in database asynchronously in background thread upon button click and we add notification block in main thread to update the no of people in count label. Each thread (main and background ) have its own instance of realm object to access Realm Database. Because Realm Database achieves thread safety by making instances of Realm thread-confined.

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    convenience init(_ name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let realmMain = try!  Realm ()
    self.people = realmMain.objects(Person.self)
    self.notification = self.people?.addNotificationBlock{ [weak self] changes in
        print("UI update needed")
        guard let countLabel = self?.countLabel else {
            return
        }
        countLabel.text = "Total People: \(String(describing: self?.people?.count))"
    }
}

@IBAction func addHandler(_ sender: Any) {
    print(#function)
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue",
                                        qos: .background,
                                        target: nil)



    backgroundQueue.async {
        print("Dispatched to background queue")
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            for i in 1..<50 {
                let name = String(format: "rajan-%d", i)
                //print(#function, name)
                realm.add(Person(name))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get

```
Realm accessed from incorrect thread
```

if you try to write by fetched item

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a ThreadSafe reference, a specific way to pass realm objects between threads:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let person = Person(name: "Jane") // no primary key required 
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person)
}
let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)
DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myApp.bg").async {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    guard let person = realm.resolve(personRef) else {
    return // person was deleted
}
try! realm.write {
    person.name = "Jane Doe"
}
```

The steps provided by Realm Documentation:

1. Initialize a ThreadSafeReference with the thread-confined object.
2. Pass that ThreadSafeReference to a destination thread or queue.
3. Resolve this reference on the target Realm by calling
   Realm.resolve(_:).
4. Use the returned object as you normally would.